# [Aspell][C][Pipes] Child and Parent - Redirection with pipe - Unix C

Tags: c, unix, pipe

**Code:**

```
int pf[2], fp[2];

pipe(pf);
pipe(fp);
pid_t parent = getpid();
pid_t child = fork();
char str[20];
char word[20] = "aspell -a test";
char buffer[100];
int count;
//dup2(0, pf[0]);

if (child != 0) {
    char resu[100];

    printf("I am the parent process. My PID is %d\n", parent);

    sleep(5);
    printf("Escrevi a palavra...\n");
    write(pf[1], "teste\n", strlen("teste\n"));
    close(pf[1]);
    sleep(2);
    count = read(fp[0], resu, strlen(resu));
    close(fp[0]);


    printf("resultado: %s\n", resu);

else {
    //printf("I am the child process. My PID is %d\n", getpid());
    //printf("    My parent's PID is %d\n", parent);
    execlp("aspell", "aspell", "-a", NULL);
    dup2(pf[0], 0);
    dup2(1, fp[1]);
    close(1);
    //close(pf[0]);

    execlp("aspell", "aspell", "-a", NULL);

    sleep(2);

    printf("Child process terminating\n");   
}
```

For above code, it always print

> resultado:

Why does this happen? The fp[0] dont read correctly?

The "resultado: " should be the stdout of the child process and simply either it appears garbage or nothing appears.

Comment: As it is it's a compiler error but it could be simply a copy/paste error: The closing brace `}` before `else` is missing. Please, [edit] your question and fix this.

Comment: `if (child != 0)` is not the correct test (or there is one missing). Please, consider that `fork()` may return `-1` if it fails. You should test this as well.

Comment: Concerning your `pipe()` issue. The tests for failing are missing here also. (May be, this is a reason but nobody can say.) However, I'm not that familiar with pipe programming (less than with using them). Have you tried google? There are plenty of examples, e.g. [C program to demonstrate fork() and pipe()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-demonstrate-fork-and-pipe/) and [Redirect stdout using dup](https://cboard.cprogramming.com/linux-programming/101247-redirect-stdout-using-dup.html).